# The circle of 51

Tags: riddle

> I am the circle of life and death
>
> I gave birth to puzzling
>
> I gave death to literature
>
> As I'm associated with the number 51,
>
> One may call me the circle of 51

What am I?

Comment: I don't like this kind of riddles. The answer is related to this site when I'm trying to think in generic terms. It's disappointing.

Comment: @cst1992 Thank you for your input. I will take it in consideration when creating a new puzzle. (But, judging by the number of votes on the question, I don't think that many people agree with you.)

Comment: That indicates that the question was good; not the expected answer. You'll find more votes on questions that are really difficult. That's another matter that people may get frustrated if a riddle is **too** hard or has a very boring answer or similar. If I'm not wrong, you have another question which is very similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Area 51

I am the circle of life and death

> I am the place where stack exchange sites are given life -- or not.

I gave birth to puzzling

> See previous clue with regard to this site.

I gave death to literature

> "The Literature site didn't have enough activity during the beta, and has been closed. You can download the data dump of all questions here."

As I'm associated with the number 51,

> The site's name is "Area 51"

One may call me the circle of 51

> Not sure of this; there is a portion of a circular two-dimensional depiction of a planet or moon at the top of the Area 51 background, or perhaps it has something to do with the fact that a circle is a geometric figure whose area is often calculated.

Comment: Correct. Usually answers also include a justification of the answer, i.e. an explaination why the answer is correct with the clues.

Comment: @wythagoras Ok, I'm not sure on all the clues but here goes.

Comment: @cst1992 perhaps you should post that comment on the "question" rather than on the answer.

Comment: @phoog You're right. I've moved it.